# How to create class with no default constructor

Tags: java, android, lombok

I want to create a class like "android.view.View", a class that will show "There is no default constructor available in 'android.view.View'" error if super(...) is not called in class that extend my class, sorry for my bad english, is there anyone can help me? thanks

--edit

@Eran, thanks, your comment gives me a hint, so the culprit is Lombok annotation "@Data", it gives no error even I create a constructor with parameter, any idea how to achieve this with Lombok?

Comment: Create a class having a constructor with parameters.

Comment: Just add a constructor with at least one parameter to your class. The compiler only adds a default constructor if you don't define any constructor yourself in the class.

Comment: @Eran, thanks, your comment gives me a hint, so the culprit is Lombok annotation "@Data", it gives no error even I create a constructor with parameter, any idea how to achieve this with Lombok?

Comment: Just to get the usage right: a *default* constructor is a constructor provided automatically if you don’t declare a constructor yourself. A *no-arg* constructor is a constructor that takes no arguments. The default constructor is a no-arg constructor, but you may also declare a no-arg constructor yourself. This is enough to ensure that there will be no default constructor by the definition I just gave.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just provide the private constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer for now, this only show exception at run time, not tested though, i want to produce the error before compile if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can make it private so other classes can't use it.

```
public class MyClass{
    private String text;
    private int number;

    private MyClass(){
        this.text="hi";
    }

    public MyClass(int number){
        this();
        this.number = number
    }
    ...
}
```

In this way, child classes should use the non default constructor:

```
public MyChildClass1 extends MyClass{
    //NO COMPILE: No default constructor available in MyClass
}

public MyChildClass2 extends MyClass{
    public MyChildClass2(){
        //NO COMPILE: No default constructor available in MyClass
    }
}

public MyChildClass3 extends MyClass{
    public MyChildClass3(){
        super(); //NO COMPILE: MyClass() has private access
    }
}

public MyChildClass4 extends MyClass{
    public MyChildClass4(){
        super(2); //It Works! (it will initialize number=2 and text="hi")
    }
}
```

Comment: how a private field can force child class to use at least one super(..)?

Comment: @g03r03 I'm not sure I have understood your comment. I have updated te answer with what I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your main class pattern.

```
public class MyParentClass {

    MyParentClass(int value) {

    }
}
```

If any class want to extend it without calling `super(value)` will get **"There is no default contructor available in parent_class_name"**

Like as below:

```
public class ChildClass extends MyParentClass {

}
```

Comment: Yes this is how i created my class, i thought i make mistake, but then i finally realized, this class not produce any error if I use "@Data" annotation from Lombok

    public @Data class ChildClass extends MyParentClass {
    
    }